# Scrapy has different results in Python shell and cmd.exe

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I use Scrapy to write a spider that to get something on dmoz.org.

When I use `response.xpath` in the Python shell to check, I get what I want, however when I run this spider in cmd, I don't get anything. I'm confused.

Here is my spider's code:

```
import scrapy
from kecheng3.items import Kecheng3Item

class DmozSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz_spider"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for divm in response.xpath('//*[@id="site-list-content"]/div'):
            item = Kecheng3Item()
            item['title'] = divm.xpath('/div[3]/a/div/text()').extract()
            item['link'] = divm.xpath('/div[3]/a/@href').extract()
            item['desc'] = divm.xpath('/div[3]/div/text()').extract()
            yield item
```

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
item['title'] = divm.xpath('./div[3]/a/div/text()').extract()
item['link'] = divm.xpath('./div[3]/a/@href').extract()
item['desc'] = divm.xpath('./div[3]/div/text()').extract()
```

`/` means root

`./` means current node, in your case, the `divm` node.

This is by default, you can do this way:

```
item['title'] = divm.xpath('div[3]/a/div/text()').extract()
```